# How can I activate Setter of property whenever the __init__ function is called?

Tags: python

I'm making a program where I want to verify if the induced value is the right one.
Imagine I want to create an object with a property called `name`. That name must be a string, right? Well, I would like to verify this by running this piece of code:

```
    def SetName(self, name):
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise ValueError("It must be a string")
        self._name = name
```

This is my `__init__` :

```
    def __init__(self, name:str, price:int, note = None) -> None:
        self._name = name
        self._price = price
        self.note = note
        Product.listOfProducts.append(self)
```

This code works when I input a string, like this:

```
    Margerita = P.Pizza("Margerita", 15, ["Cheese", "Basil"], 10)
```

However, if I run:

```
    Margerita = P.Pizza(5, 15, ["Cheese", "Basil"], 10)
```

It raises no error.

What can I do to make the property:

```
    name = property(fget = GetName, fset = SetName)
```

Work as I described it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Assign a value to `self.name` or call `SetName` in `__init__` instead of assigning a value to `self._name`.

Comment: Like `SetName(name)` ??

Comment: Yep. `self.SetName(name)` inside your `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your approach with a dedicated setter function for each argument, you could use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) in combination with a [`__post_init__`](https://testdriven.io/tips/94ca0d2c-4c0d-4b8f-9762-6daa11d504f7/) check for a generalized type check:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

list_of_products = []

@dataclass
class Pizza:
    name: str
    price: int
    condiments: list

    def __post_init__(self):
        for (name, arg_type) in self.__annotations__.items():
            if not isinstance(self.__dict__[name], arg_type):
                raise TypeError(
                    f"`{name}` must be `{arg_type.__name__}` "
                    f"(was `{self.__dict__[name].__class__.__name__}`)"
                )
        # various other manipulations previously done in your __init__
        list_of_products.append(self)
        # [...]


margerita = Pizza("foo", 15, ["spam"])  # valid
m4rg3rita = Pizza(42, 15, ["spam"])  # <= raises TypeError: `name` must be `str` (was `int`)
```